# map/multiply values to logical vector

Tags: matlab

Although I have a quite simple question, I didn't find an answer in older posts. What I would like to do (in a fairly elegant way) is to map/multiply values from one vector to the logical true elements in another vector, keeping it's dimensionality.
so, let's assume I have two vectors, one logical one like

```
a = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
```

and another integer one like

```
b = [3,1,7,4]
```

I would now want to multiply them so that I receive a vector:

```
c = [3,1,0,0,7,0,4,0]
```

Sorry if I'm missing the obvious here but I just didn't find an answer somewhere else.

Comment: how do you multiply these in math? the dimension matters. Is you question that: how to replace the 1 (true) values in the vector a with values in vector b?

Comment: My Matlab is broken right now, if it weren't I'd try `c = a; c(a==1) = a(a==1).*b`

Comment: yes, you're right! I would like to replace the 1's with the values from the other vector! exactly!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: thank you so much! works like a charm! I guess I really missed the obvious here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit if `a` is genuinely of type logical or just happens to contain 0/1. If it is logical you can index directly with it:

```
c = zeros(size(a));
c(a)=b;
```

If it is not, see Divakar's answer.

Comment: as `a` is genuinely logical, you're answer is perfect! thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be this -

```
c = a;
c(find(a==1)) = b;
```

Comment: @nkjt I am assuming a strict case where a is not a logical array and want to make sure that I am doing a numeral comparison with `1`. Of course, I am assigning "perfect zeros" to a in `a = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]`, but still.

Comment: this works fine, even if `a` wouldn't be of type logical. thanks!

Comment: @kro sure would! Just making fully sure it works fine with my rocket launching when used there :)